# How to customize the position of clrdgfilter using clarity?

Tags: vmware-clarity

[image: Customize the clrdgfilter position]

How to customize the position of clrdgfilter shown in the image? Here i am not able to change the position using clarity customize options. Please suggest me the solution with working demo in stackblitz

Comment: The offscreen and clipping issues have been fixed in v2.2.0.

Comment: But right now in the project we are using version 0.10 of clarity

Comment: The best path to fixing the issue is to upgrade to v2.2.1.